# How to get value of variable entered from user input with really easy way?

Tags: python, variables, integer, output

i want to Write a piece of code that repeatedly asks for input until the user enters your first name correctly. Once the user enters specific name, print a positive message congratulating the user. if not it will ask again until the user will put the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
correct_name = 'John'
print('Enter your first name:')
name = input()
while name != correct_name:
    print('Incorrect. Please enter your first name:')
    name = input()
print('Correct')
```